# ng-repeat and repeated radio button groups

Tags: angularjs

I see similar questions everywhere, but I still can't see where I am going wrong here. (Still somewhat new to angular)

I have a series of repeated items and for each item I want to create a radio group where the user selects an item for each repeated line. The problem is that each button group isn't unique. Clicking on any one button selects the first instance. How do I make the groups unique?

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in availableText track by obj.id" class="possibleTextBlock">
    <div ng-class="obj.textClass" ng-click="handleText(obj.id)">{{obj.text}}</div>
    <div class="parseOptionLine">
        <radiogroup id="$index">
            <div class="parseOption"><input type="radio" id="Parsers0+$index" name="parseAdd+$index" ng-model="obj.parser" ng-value="Parsers[0]"><label for="Parsers0+$index"><span></span>{{Parsers[0]}}</label></div>
            <div class="parseOption"><input type="radio" id="Parsers1+$index" name="parseAdd+$index" ng-model="obj.parser" ng-value="Parsers[1]"><label for="Parsers1+$index"><span></span>{{Parsers[1]}}</label></div>
            <div class="parseOption"><input type="radio" id="Parsers2+$index" name="parseAdd+$index" ng-model="obj.parser" ng-value="Parsers[2]"><label for="Parsers2+$index"><span></span>{{Parsers[2]}}</label></div>
            <div class="parseOption"><input type="radio" id="Parsers3+$index" name="parseAdd+$index" ng-model="obj.parser" ng-value="Parsers[3]"><label for="Parsers3+$index"><span></span>{{Parsers[3]}}</label></div>
            <div class="parseOption"><input type="radio" id="Parsers4+$index" name="parseAdd+$index" ng-model="obj.parser" ng-value="Parsers[4]"><label for="Parsers4+$index"><span></span>{{Parsers[4]}}</label></div>
        </radiogroup>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't include the controller as I think I am missing something simple in the names for the buttons or the radio groups.

Thanks

Comment: If i dont misthink that, you seem to have same value on it as ng-model="obj.parser", not sure tho(today finished 2 days angularjs training)

Comment: I was under the impression that the obj "would" iterate with each repeat so that each radio group was tied to the correct value of that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in Developer tools that Parsers0+$index for id, name and other attributes is not replaced with index when the view is rendered. So all the rendered radio buttons are under one group name Parsers0+$index, so the groups are not unique. Correct syntax to replace the index value in your case is
    `Parsers0{{$index}}`
 and this should make your groups unique.
here is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/IIPnjXnH5aKptyZ7e47T?p=preview